# Send bidimensional array in php in form without serialize

Tags: php, arrays, forms, foreach

I'm having problems trying to send a multi-dimensional array in a form. I'm receiving an error in the second `foreach`:

```
foreach($basearray as $index1 => $value1) {
    foreach ($value1 as $index2 => $finalvalue) {
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="horario[' . $index1 . ']" value="' . $finalvalue . '">';
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is generating the name, but not sure how to do it.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: "I'm receiving an error in the second foreach." is it a national security aspect to hide the specific error message for us?

Comment: Sorry, as i thought the error was at generating the name in the echo i didn't especified the error:Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @user3215273 that means `$value1` isn't something that `foreach` knows how to iterate over. Can you post the output of `var_dump($basearray);`?

Comment: var_dump($basearray) and post the result.

Comment: array(1) { ["08:00"]=> array(1) { ["monday"]=> string(6) "Lengua" } }

Comment: I think the echo is not sending the bidimensional array correctly so when the page receives it and processes it again appears the error